# R shiny module outputs different plot types based on user input in each of the two tabs

Tags: r, shiny

The problem is, the plots type cannot be changed according to chart type selection.

I try to make R shiny output different plot types based on user input in each of the multiple tabs. Because there are many tabs, I use modules. This example only shows two tabs with the `iris` data:

- two tab items: `setosa` and `versicolor`
- two tabpanels: `Petal.Length` or `Petal.Width`
- two plot type: pie and bar

All work except that **only setosa - Petal.Length gives pie plot; all other plots are bar plots, and they cannot be changed according to chart type selection.**
Here is the code. Thank you for help.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(echarts4r)

# example data
data(iris)

irises <- iris


### module UI
# menuItem ui
menuItem_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id) 
  menuItem(
    tabName = id,
    text = id
  )
}


# tabPanel ui - sub module of tabItem ui
# f: Petal.Length or Petal.Width; g: graph; t: table
tabPanel_ui <- function(id, f) {
  ns <- NS(id) # namespace function
  
  table_module <- paste0("table_mod_", f)
  graph_module <- paste0("graph_mod_", f)
  
  tabPanel(title = f,
             box(width = 8,
                echarts4rOutput(ns(graph_module))
             ),
            box(width = 4,
            h6(paste0(f, " - ", id)),

            tableOutput(ns(table_module)),

           hr(style = "border-top: 1px solid #87CEEB;"),
               
               selectInput("graph_type", 
                           label = "Choose a chart type",
                           choices = c("Pie", "Bar"),
                           selected = "Pie")
          ) 
  ) # end tabPanel

}


# tabItem ui
tabItem_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id) 

  tabItem(
    tabName = id,

    fluidRow(
      tabBox(width = 12,
             tabPanel_ui(id, "Petal.Length"), 
             tabPanel_ui(id, "Petal.Width")
      )
    )

  ) # end tabItem 
}


# module Server
# f: Petal.Length or Petal.Width, g: graph type
tab_server <- function(id, f, g) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    ns <- session$ns ## call namespace in the server
    
    table_module <- paste0("table_mod_", f)
    graph_module <- paste0("graph_mod_", f)

    
    fData <- irises %>%
      filter(Species == id) %>%
      group_by_(f) %>%
      dplyr::summarise(n = n()) %>%
      mutate(percent = n/sum(n))
    
    
    # Table ----
    output[[table_module]] <- renderTable({
      head(fData)
    })
    

    # graph ----
    output[[graph_module]] <- renderEcharts4r({
      if(g == "Pie"){
        fData %>%
          e_charts_(f) %>%
          e_pie(percent, name = f) %>%
          e_title(f)
      }else{
        fData %>%
          e_charts_(f) %>%
          e_bar(percent, name = f) %>%
          e_title(f)
      }
    })
    
  }) 
} 


##### UI #####
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
    title = "Graph Type"
  ),
  
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem_ui("setosa"),
      menuItem_ui("versicolor")
    )
  ),
  
  dashboardBody(
    title = "Graph Type",
    
    tabItems(
      tabItem_ui("setosa"),
      tabItem_ui("versicolor")

    ) 
  )
)

##### Server #####
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  ### choose graph type
  graphType <- reactive({
    input$graph_type
  })

  
  tab_server("setosa", "Petal.Length", graphType())
  tab_server("setosa", "Petal.Width", graphType())

  tab_server("versicolor", "Petal.Length", graphType())
  tab_server("versicolor", "Petal.Width", graphType())
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with your code.

1. An `id` has to be unique, whereas in your app the same `id`s are  used multiple times.
2. IMHO, there is only one module for the `tabPanel`s whereas `menuItem_ui` and `tabItem_ui` are simply convenience functions to create the menu and tab items per species.
3. To make the distinction clear I renamed the `id` argument in all of your functions to `species`. Additionally I renamed your `tab_server` to `tabPanel_server` to make clear that this is the server part of the `tabPanel` module. Inside `tabPanel_ui` and `tabPanel_server` I use `id <- paste(species, f, sep = "-")` to create unique `id`s from the species name and the variable name.
4. As `graph_type` is the `id` of the `selectInput` in the `tabPanel_ui` you could wrap it inside `ns()` and then use `input$graph_type` in the `tabPanel_server`, i.e. there is no need to add a reactive in the main server or to pass the the value of this `reactive` to the `tabPanel_server`.
5. `group_by_` is deprecated. Instead you could use the `.data` pronoun, i.e. do `group_by(.data[[f]])`.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(echarts4r)

# example data
data(iris)

irises <- iris

# menuItem ui
menuItem_ui <- function(species) {
  menuItem(
    tabName = species,
    text = species
  )
}

# tabItem ui
tabItem_ui <- function(species) {
  tabItem(
    tabName = species,
    fluidRow(
      tabBox(
        width = 12,
        tabPanel_ui(species, "Petal.Length"),
        tabPanel_ui(species, "Petal.Width")
      )
    )
  )
}

# tabPanel ui - sub module of tabItem ui
# f: Petal.Length or Petal.Width; g: graph; t: table
tabPanel_ui <- function(species, f) {
  id <- paste(species, f, sep = "-")
  
  ns <- NS(id)

  table_module <- paste0("table_mod_", f)
  graph_module <- paste0("graph_mod_", f)

  tabPanel(
    title = f,
    box(
      width = 8,
      echarts4rOutput(ns(graph_module))
    ),
    box(
      width = 4,
      h6(paste0(f, " - ", species)),
      tableOutput(ns(table_module)),
      hr(style = "border-top: 1px solid #87CEEB;"),
      selectInput(ns("graph_type"),
        label = "Choose a chart type",
        choices = c("Pie", "Bar"),
        selected = "Pie"
      )
    )
  )
}

# module Server
# f: Petal.Length or Petal.Width, g: graph type
tabPanel_server <- function(species, f) {
  id <- paste(species, f, sep = "-")
  
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    table_module <- paste0("table_mod_", f)
    graph_module <- paste0("graph_mod_", f)

    fData <- irises %>%
      filter(Species == species) %>%
      group_by(.data[[f]]) %>%
      summarise(n = n()) %>%
      mutate(percent = n / sum(n))

    # Table ----
    output[[table_module]] <- renderTable({
      head(fData)
    })

    # graph ----
    output[[graph_module]] <- renderEcharts4r({
      if (input$graph_type == "Pie") {
        fData %>%
          e_charts_(f) %>%
          e_pie(percent, name = f) %>%
          e_title(f)
      } else {
        fData %>%
          e_charts_(f) %>%
          e_bar(percent, name = f) %>%
          e_title(f)
      }
    })
  })
}

##### UI #####
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
    title = "Graph Type"
  ),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem_ui("setosa"),
      menuItem_ui("versicolor")
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    title = "Graph Type",
    tabItems(
      tabItem_ui("setosa"),
      tabItem_ui("versicolor")
    )
  )
)

##### Server #####
server <- function(input, output) {
  tabPanel_server("setosa", "Petal.Length")
  tabPanel_server("setosa", "Petal.Width")

  tabPanel_server("versicolor", "Petal.Length")
  tabPanel_server("versicolor", "Petal.Width")
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @stefan for the answers. It works great. In addition, the detailed explanations help a lot!